# Error using alias for routes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a route with a namespace

```
namespace :publishers do
    resources :authors
    get 'books' :to => 'books'
    get 'books/custom_report/:id', :to => "curriculos#custom_report"
end
```

Often I will have to make links in my application and I know than it`s possible to use a alias for routing like this:

```
<%= link_to "Books", publishers_books_path %>
```

I call that **publishers_books_path** a alias route, does this is the correct name?

Furthermore, I still not able to understand the logic with this alias naming because i can`t use for a new or a custom action like this

```
link_to 'Show the report', publishers_books_custom_report_path(params[:id])
```

I'm always get a error of undefined_method for `publishers_books_custom_report_path`

So there`s some questions

1. First of all whats it`s the correct name of this feature in RoR?
2. How I can use the custom_report as aliases to link_to? And also if i need to use some basic operations like new, update, insert?
3. Can someone give me the link to the documentation to really understant that feature?

Comment: There's a missing comma in `get 'books' :to => 'books'`. Is that a typo in the question or the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First of all whats it`s the correct name of this feature in RoR?

The docs use "path helper" and "named route helpers" interchangeably.

> How I can use the custom_report as aliases to link_to?

Use `rails route` or visit `/rails/info/routes` in your dev server to get a list of all your routes, their helpers, and controller actions.

Apparently it is `publishers_path` which doesn't seem right. You can fix this with an `as`.

```
get 'books/custom_report/:id', to: "curriculos#custom_report", as: :books_custom_report
```

> And also if i need to use some basic operations like new, update,
> insert?

A `get` declares just that one specific route. If you need all the operations on a model, declare it as a `resource`.

```
  namespace :publishers do
    resource :authors
    resource :books
    get 'books/custom_report/:id', to: "curriculos#custom_report", as: :books_custom_report
  end
```

> Can someone give me the link to the documentation to really understand that feature?

[Rails Routing From The Outside In](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).

Comment: Good answer. I would add that `get 'books/custom_report/:id'` is quite unidimatic.  The idiomatic way would be `get 'books/:id/custom_report'` see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions and also the comment on avoiding deep nesting.

Comment: `resource :books do; get :custom_report, on: :member, controller: 'curriculos': end`